# How to downsample my data readings from 0.5hz to 0.001667hz. Do I filter and downsample?

Tags: filtering, downsampling

I have a device that, in the lab, takes voltage readings every 2 seconds. However in real-life application the device would only wake every 10 minutes and then take a 100 readings whilst awake. How do i change my collected data to mirror real-life application? Only then can I interpret if my device is working as it should. I see from reading various posts that downsampling alone is not appropriate.

Comment: So, to get this straight: you get 100 values with 2s in between, then you go to sleep for 10 min - 200s = 400s, then you continue? Sounds like you really just need to *throw away* data. The question is whether that simulated or the areal-world collected data then still is useful, and that can't be answered without you telling us what kind of signal that voltage signal is.

Comment: Yes Marcus you are correct in identifying the sleep/reading pattern. The values coming into Realterm are discrete values. So yes I need to keep 100 values, dump the next 300 values, keep 100 values, dump 300 .....I had thought this was downsampling but I wasnt sure how to keep 100 values rather than just 1, which is what I would get with a decimating factor.

Comment: Well it sounds like you have two ranges of time-frequency information-- You have high rate information with a sampling period of 2 seconds, and then you have low rate information with a sampling period of 10 minutes. As for the low rate information, you can simply average the 100 samples you get to get the one sample for each 10 minute period. As for the high rate, each capture will indicate what occured over that time interval (you could average the powers easily enough-- anything else in the very low freq range would be revealed in the avged one sample from each over all averaged samples).

Comment: (The averaging and then keeping the one sample is the filter and downsample)

Comment: Thanks Dan. So I filter first and downsample afterwards. What type of filter I should use in MATLAB? There are so many parameters linked to each filter description that I am lost wrt to knowing which to apply to my data.

Comment: @SuzanneO'Callaghan Dan proposed that you, based on a model of your signal's realities, average. that would be a rectangular filter; however, I doubt you're doing much sensible stuff here if you're not considering what signal you're observing for what purpose. Could you elaborate on that? Recommending a filter isn't possible without knowing it.

Comment: ok so I have made a bluetooth wireless device which reads voltage values from a sensor every 2 seconds. The data is transmitted wirelessly in Ansi @ 115200 baud rate to Realterm Serial Capture Software on my pc. The data is stored as a text file and contains approximately 45,000 values. The data should only be read as follows: 1. read 100 values, sleep 10 minutes, read 100 values etc.  i need to dump the data recorded during the 'sleep' cycle and then i need just 1 averaged value from each remaining block of 100 samples.

Comment: Im not sure how else to describe the signal to you as I havent done signal processing for over 15 years and to say i am rusty is an understatement.